# SKYPE4COMLib unable to send message to another user

Tags: c#, winforms, skype, skype4com

We are doing windows based automation software that uses skype com library.

With SKYPE4COMLib i am trying to send message to another skype user from C# application with below given code.

```
var friendSelected = listBox1.SelectedItem;
            foreach (User user in skype.Friends)
            {
                ChatMessage LiveMess = new ChatMessage();
                if (user.Handle == friendSelected.ToString())
                    LiveMess = skype.SendMessage(user.Handle, "Nice Well");
            }
```

Even though method skype.SendMessage is executing properly without any exception. It is not sending message across.

Any help in this case will be helpful.

Comment: That library was discontinued half a decade ago.  Google "skype4com alternatives" to find existing questions about it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue can you tell what worked for you.